# Please identify this plant

Tags: botany, species-identification, plant-anatomy

I don't know anything about plants

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome!!! to Biology Stack Exchange. You should add [tag:species-identification] tag to your question. And also please provide information about your location and size of the leaf.

Comment: Try to use a more descriptive title. Give details about what you observed.

Comment: Any fruits ever develop? Looks like Solanaceae to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not my area of expertise... but looking at the pictures, it looks like it has a distinctly square stem. This is a characteristic of the mint family 
[Lamiaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamiaceae); the leaves look reasonable... but that's obviously an incomplete answer and not definitive.

Note that there are some iPhone & Android apps that help; look up '[LeafSnap](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/leafsnap/id430649829?mt=8)' for example (I think that one's iPhone only and perhaps limited to trees)

Answer (score -1):

I'm no plant expert, but it looks a lot like a cucumber plant.  We used to have them in our vegetable garden.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 